# Insufficient memory to run Java Runtime environment to continue

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have a system with 4 GB of RAM with Windows OS. I installed VMWare to set up Ubuntu Virtual machine with 2GB RAM. In Ubuntu, I opened Eclipse and started coding and Eclipse started closing again and again and I started getting the following error:

```
 There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.     Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 28311552 bytes for     committing reserved memory.
Possible reasons:
 The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
 Possible solutions:
   Reduce memory load on the system
   Increase physical memory or swap space
   Check if swap backing store is full
   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
   Decrease number of Java threads
   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
 This output file may be truncated or incomplete.

  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2640), pid=4608, tid=0x6dc6eb40

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_161-b12) (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.161-b12 mixed mode linux-x86 )
 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x099ab400):  VMThread [stack: 0x6dbee000,0x6dc6f000] [id=4629]

Stack: [0x6dbee000,0x6dc6f000],  sp=0x6dc6d240,  free space=508k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x5bffaf]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x16f
V  [libjvm.so+0x20e115]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned int, VMErrorType, char const*)+0x55
V  [libjvm.so+0x4a2686]  os::Linux::commit_memory_impl(char*, unsigned int, bool)+0xe6
V  [libjvm.so+0x4a2afd]  os::pd_commit_memory_or_exit(char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, char const*)+0x2d
V  [libjvm.so+0x49c660]  os::commit_memory_or_exit(char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, char const*)+0x30
V  [libjvm.so+0x2741ad]  G1PageBasedVirtualSpace::commit_internal(unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x9d
V  [libjvm.so+0x27440c]  G1PageBasedVirtualSpace::commit(unsigned int, unsigned int)+0xfc
V  [libjvm.so+0x276a68]  G1RegionsLargerThanCommitSizeMapper::commit_regions(unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x28
V  [libjvm.so+0x2bc2ba]  HeapRegionManager::commit_regions(unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x5a
V  [libjvm.so+0x2bd343]  HeapRegionManager::make_regions_available(unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x23
V  [libjvm.so+0x2bd851]  HeapRegionManager::expand_by(unsigned int)+0xa1
V  [libjvm.so+0x250a7c]  G1CollectedHeap::expand(unsigned int)+0x11c
V  [libjvm.so+0x25b3fa]  G1CollectedHeap::do_collection_pause_at_safepoint(double)+0xd5a
V  [libjvm.so+0x5cbafe]  VM_G1IncCollectionPause::doit()+0x6e
V  [libjvm.so+0x5caad7]  VM_Operation::evaluate()+0x47
V  [libjvm.so+0x5c8ba3]  VMThread::evaluate_operation(VM_Operation*)+0xb3
V  [libjvm.so+0x5c8f40]  VMThread::loop()+0x1b0
V  [libjvm.so+0x5c93a5]  VMThread::run()+0x85
V  [libjvm.so+0x4a5219]  java_start(Thread*)+0x119
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x6295]  start_thread+0xe5

VM_Operation (0xbfbfede0): G1IncCollectionPause, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0988f800

--------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the list of suggestions the error gives you?

Comment: @Shawn can you explain how exactly we can do those suggestions which are going to workout.

Comment: The suggestions with parameters starting with `-` can be set in `eclipse.ini` in separate lines below `-vmargs`. The other suggestions refer to operating system settings. If you have a 64-bit system, you can use [Eclipse OpenJ9](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk10&jvmVariant=openj9#x64_linux) instead of the Java HotSpot VM to reduce memory load on the system.

Answer (score 3):

The **Java virtual machine process runs out of memory**.

There are several possibilities what you could do. In my view, the following possibilities are the most promising if you want to keep the current restrictions for the process:

- **Decrease** Java heap size (**`-Xmx`**/`-Xms`):
  In **`eclipse.ini`** there is probably a line like `-Xmx1024m` that you could replace with for example `-Xmx640m`. Try out which maximum heap space is still sufficient for your needs. Make sure `-Xms` is not greater than `-Xmx`.
- If and only if you have a 64-bit system, you can use Eclipse 64-bit and **[Eclipse OpenJ9](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk10&jvmVariant=openj9#x64_linux) instead of** Eclipse 32-bit and the **Java HotSpot 32-bit VM** you are currently using. By default, OpenJ9 is more efficient in terms of memory consumption and can also be further tuned in this respect.

The possibility `Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS` seems to be given improperly here, because a 64-bit Java VM can address more memory, but is less memory efficient than the equivalent 32-bit VM.

Comment: Yeaa I did what you suggested but still facing the same issue only decreased the Xmx value from 1024m to the 640 m but still problem persist?

Comment: Eclipse likes a lot of memory.  Running it on a 2 GB Linux system is a bit optimistic.  Perhaps with a lot of swap.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen As a Java application, Eclipse cannot occupy more memory than is given by the VM with `-Xmx` (and even a heap space less than 640m for Eclipse should be sufficient for most situations). One of the proposed solutions by the error message is to decrease Java heap size, not to increase it.

Comment: With `-Xmx640m` the Java VM process should not occupy more than 2 GB. The error message says _"Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 28311552 bytes"_. 28311552 bytes = 27 MB. If 27 MB is set as total limit for the VM process, it is too less. Otherwise, please tell the maximum memory limit for the VM and show the `eclipse.ini` file and the command to start Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You have too little memory available to eclipse. Best is to upgrade your system with more ram.

Unless you have good reason not to then use eclipse directly under windows without using virtual box. If you must use Ubuntu consider using a 32-bit version of Ubuntu and Java and eclipse, or install Ubuntu next to windows so you can boot into it and have all your memory.

Comment: Actually till yesterday it was working , I am facing this issue from today..even I tried restarting the VM as well but didn't work can you please explain is there any way to fix this issue with the present system config?

Comment: Give the vm half a gigabyte more of ram.

Comment: 512MB right? will it affect my windows system in anyway?? ofcourse if I parallel use my system and vm my windows system performance will decrease..other than that will it affect in any means?

Comment: If that concerns you, create a dual boot installation.

Comment: Actually what I did not get is like till yesterday it worked fine for me I am facing this issue from today only..is there any other way to clean up some memory in ubuntu(which type of memory I can clean and how)..because if I increase the RAM of vm now..in future that might not be also sufficient and again I may face the same problem..so is there any way to clean up some memory in ubuntu(in VM)??

Comment: Yes. Reread all the advice you been given so far. Last resort is to add more swap space.

Comment: Reread comments so far??? no-one given any solution how to clear memory without adding extra RAM to vm host

Comment: I think it's the other way around, Eclipse has too much memory available, so the limitations of the Java VM process are exceeded.

Comment: You can add more swap space to the Linux VM (easiest is perhaps just creating a swapfile, harder to add an extra virtual disk and make it swap space).  This will give the appearance of more memory but slower.  It is a workaround though.  Any reason you cannot just run Eclipse in Windows?